# After repointing DNS with TTL 24 hours, can I use page redirects

Tags: redirect, dns

I have an existing COM domain with TTL 24 hours. I will be re-pointing the COM domain (A and CNAME records only) to a new website within a few hours.

The new website is already functioning with a NET domain, so it's live online. I'm leaving the COM domain DNS with the old hosting as we have email there.

To handle the 24 hour lag, can I use DNS URL redirects to send visitors to pages on the new, until propagation is complete?

Or can I use a simple HTML redirect to do similar job?

I think the DNS URL redirect is easier for me to set up but will it work, considering the COM will already have been changed?

Answer (score 1):

First off, it's important to plan ahead.  If you have a 24 hour TTL, lower it at least 24 hours in advance of the changeover.  This would avoid your dilemma (or rather, shorten it to your new, lowered TTL)

From the description, it sounds like the .com and .net sites are identical.  Since you didn't mention any database, I assume these are static sites that don't save data to a database.  If so, you really could just leave the sites alone and not worry about a redirect.  If you want to get people onto the new server asap, use a temporary HTTP redirect or an HTML-based one.

If you *do* persist data to a database, are you also migrating that at the same time or are the two sites using the same database server?   Migrating database servers is a complicated affair, beyond what we can answer here.

(n.b. There is no "DNS URL" redirect.   That's just a service that some DNS providers offer, built on top of HTTP and DNS.  Setting it up would suffer from the same TTL lag time you're trying to avoid)